# django2 migrations ProgrammingError

Tags: django, django-migrations

Since I moved from django 1.8 to 2.1 I frequently get db migration errors. It doesn't occur during the migration directly, but when `manage.py` is called:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "obj1_obj2" does not exist
LINE 1: ....
```

Migration doesn't even start but it defines the relation or any model changes that cause the errors.

When working locally I usually rollback code and then make migrations, but on cloud providers it is useless solution. I work on python 3.6

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 350, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 60, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 396, in check
     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/aliz/urls.py", line 8, in <module>
     from camps.urls import api_urlpatterns as camps_api_urlpatterns
  File "/app/camps/urls.py", line 31, in <module>
    path('obecne/', staff_member_required(CurrentEventDetailView.as_view()), {'e_pk': Event.objects.filter(current=True).first().pk}, name='current_camps'),
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 605, in first
    for obj in (self if self.ordered else self.order_by('pk'))[:1]:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 268, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1065, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
```

Comment: As mentioned earlier, pretending to have old structure of code isn't a solution. In django 1.x migrations didn't cause such issues

Comment: The traceback shows the error is occuring because you are running `Event.objects.filter(current=True).first().pk` when your `urls.py` is loaded. You could get away with this in Django 1.8, but it causes issues since Django 1.9 when URL checks were added. You need to restructure `CurrentEventDetailView` so that you run that query when the view runs, not when the `urls.py` loads.